# Sencha Touch get last call duration

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am working on a sencha touch project there i have a requirement to get last call duration. I have a button in my UI when some one tap on that button they can execute a call, after that event i need to get the call duration to that number. I have searched a lot to get any clue but did't find one yet. Please direct me in right direction

here is my code

```
{
            xtype:'button',
            text: 'Phone',
            id:'callMeButton',
            flex:1,
            handler:function(){
               window.open('tel:+'+9496347047);
               // here i would like to get the last duration time for this number. 
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access call log on some system, like [iOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771266/iphone-access-voice-call-log).

You can do it on Android, and someone wrote a [PhoneGap plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277250/phonegap-api-to-query-call-logs) for that (you won't be able to use it with sencha though).

You can probably get the current time just before the window.open() part and then compare it with the current time when the user come back on your app's screen, but it wouldn't be very accurate neither without problems.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i will check the link and let you know the feed back